# Is there a way to count and calculate mean for text columns using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been using pandas.groupby to pivot data and create descriptive charts and tables for my data. While doing groupby for three variables, I keep running into a `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` error while working with the `cancelled` column.

To describe my data, `Year` and `Month` contain yearly and monthly data for multiple columns (multiple years, all months), `Type` contains the type of order item (Clothes, Appliances, etc.), and `cancelled` contains yes or no string values to determine whether a order was cancelled or not.

I am hoping to plot a graph and show a table to show what the cancellation rate (and success rate) is by order item. The following is what I'm using so far

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Type'])['cancelled'].mean()
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Sample

```
Year    Month        Type          cancelled 
2012      1        electronics       yes
2012      10         fiber           yes
2012      9         clothes          no
2013      4        vegetables        yes
2013      5        appliances        no
2016      3        fiber             no
2017      1        clothes           yes
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Updated - please let me know if that's helpful @EdekiOkoh

Comment: Thank you. Just an FYI for future questions. You see how after the data got posted you got answers relatively quickly. For pandas related questions always include sample data for quick responses

Comment: To add to what @EdekiOkoh said, I also recommend including desired sample output to go with sample data for future questions, as that greatly improves clarity as to what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Year':[2020] * 6,
         'Month':[7,8,7,8,7,8],
         'cancelled':['yes','no'] * 3,
         'Type':list('aaaaba')
})
print (df)
```

Get counts per `Year`, `Month`, `Type` columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Type','cancelled']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
cancelled        no  yes
Year Month Type         
2020 7     a      0    2
           b      0    1
     8     a      3    0
```

And then divide by sum of values for ratio:

```
df2 = df1.div(df1.sum()).mul(100)
print (df2)
cancelled           no        yes
Year Month Type                  
2020 7     a       0.0  66.666667
           b       0.0  33.333333
     8     a     100.0   0.000000
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this calculates percentage over the entire column. How do I only calculate the percentage within a specific month for all months?

Comment: @Mega_Noob Then change `df1 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Type','cancelled']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)` to `df1 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month','cancelled']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)`

Comment: Hi @jezrael that removes segmentation by type. I want to still have segmentation by type, but have percentage by each month. For example, in your table, if there were 1 no for `a` in month 1, and 3 no for `b` in month 1, then the table would read, 33.33% no for `a`, and 66.66% yes for `a`. Similarly, it would say 75% for no for `b` in month 1, and 25% yes for `b` in first month. Does that help in what I'm trying to get at?

Comment: @Mega_Noob - Do you think `df1 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Type','cancelled']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)` and  `df2 = df1.div(df1.sum(level=[0,1]))` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible I have misunderstood what you want your output to look like, but to find the cancellation rate for each item type, you could do something like this:

```
# change 'cancelled' to numeric values
df.loc[df['cancelled'] == 'yes', 'cancelled'] = 1
df.loc[df['cancelled'] == 'no', 'cancelled'] = 0

# get the mean of 'cancelled' for each item type
res = {}
for t in df['Type'].unique():
    res[t] = df.loc[df['Type'] == t, 'cancelled'].mean()

# if desired, put it into a dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame([res], index=['Rate']).T
```

Output:

```
              Rate
electronics   1.0
fiber         0.5
clothes       0.5
vegetables    1.0
appliances    0.0
```

Note: If you want to specify specific years or months, you can do that with `loc` as well, but given that your example data did not have any repeats within a given year or month, this would return your original dataframe for your given example.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem, but appreciate the response!